# Is it impossible to use "xlPasteAll" in Excel VBA UDF?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create Index-Match method in VBA.

To do this, i found some ideas and finally it is well-working.

But one more thing, PasteSecial is not working in User-Defined Function.

How to solve it?

Below is my code, and original website.

I just added PasteSpecial.

https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-vba-index-match-multiple-criteria/

```
Function MatchByIndex(x As Double, y As Double)
Const StartRow = 15
Dim EndRow As Long
Dim iRow As Long
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    EndRow = .Range("C:D").Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    For iRow = StartRow To EndRow
        If .Range("C" & iRow).Value = x And .Range("D" & iRow).Value = y Then
            MatchByIndex = .Range("B" & iRow).Value
            .Range("B" & iRow).Copy
            Range("H22").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next iRow
End With
MatchByIndex = "Data Not found"
End Function
```

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1#:~:text=A%20user%2Ddefined%20function%20called,Change%20another%20cell's%20value.

Comment: Do you need the formatting in `Range("H22")`?